# Как вывести элемент из listView?

Tags: java, android, listview

```
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int 

position,
long id) {
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
}
```

Position - это номер(позиция элемента), мне же нужно вывести текст из элемента.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е при клике мне нужно вывести текст который выделен жирным шрифтом в listView

Comment: При клике на элемент мне нужно вывести текст из этого элемента.

Comment: Добавил больше описания.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView textView = (TextView)itemClicked.findViewById(R.id.textView);
String text = textView.getText().toString+();
```

`itemClicked` - вьюшка айтема, она же приходит в метод `onItemClick`. Из неё ищем все что хочется по id и используем

**по настоянию @pavlofff и совести**

Получаете единицу данных.

```
Object click = adapter.getItem(position);
String first = click.getFirst();
String second = click.getSecond();
```

Методов `getFirst()` и `getSecond()` нет, я просто дал понять что нужно брать данные из модели данных например или ещё как-нибудь. Я же не знаю структуру данных. Если не понятно, выложите код адаптера

Comment: Таскать данные из представления не очень разумное решение. У адаптера есть метод `getItem()`, который вернет единицу данных, по которым заполнялось `View`

Comment: Я знаю, но он не поймёт.

Comment: это не повод для некачественных ответов, объясните так, чтобы понял. Тем более, что вы отвечаете не лично задавшему вопрос, а публикуете правильное решение проблемы.